# Difference between dates in two last items form the same order

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

I tried to look for the answer in the forum and google, but with no success.

### I have a list:

let's say:

```
'Site ID','Date requested'
11111, 2019-03-05
11110, 2019-03-15
11111, 2019-05-01
```

I want to create a column "Weeks since the last request" for the same "Site iD"

```
'Site ID','Date requested','Weeks since the last request'
11111, 2019-03-05,0
11110, 2019-03-15,0
11111, 2019-05-01,8 (rounded)
```

The best if it can be even populated with additional metadata, eg.

```
'Site ID','Date requested','Weeks since the last request','Type'
11110, 2019-03-05, 0, PSV
11111, 2019-03-05, 0, PSV
11110, 2019-03-15, 0, MV
11111, 2019-05-01, 8, PSV
```

Where the difference between 11110 PSV & MV is 0 because they are a different type, but the difference between 11111 is calculated because they are the same type.

I will be grateful for any help any resources to look into.

with best regards,
Vladimir

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint items are independent of each other. They are not rows in a table. So, you cannot write Calculated Column formulas that reach into the previous or next row for a value. (i.e. they are similar to rows in a SQL table.)

You have several ways to get to what you want...

- Write workflows that when an item is created, it checks for a previous item, and generates a value for the new item. The problem is keeping these updated when a previous item gets updated.
- Create a custom SharePoint Add-In that generates a report from the list, calculating values as the items are read from the list. (A JavaScript, HTML and CSS project.)
- Prior to the Modern UI we could add JavaScript to the page (using SharePoint Designer) that created and displayed derived data.